# When the Celery Beat send one due task, Why the MainProcess Received three different task?

Tags: python, celery

Python 3.6.5 Celery v4.2.1,
How to resolve when the Celery Beat send once due task, the MainProcess Received three task?
The Celery beat schedule:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'stats-every-midnight': {
        'task': 'tasks.stats.stats',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=0)
    }
}
```

log:

```
[2020-12-15 00:00:00,079: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task stats-every-midnight (tasks.stats.stats)
[2020-12-15 00:00:00,084: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.stats.stats[cc9206a0-228d-4eeb-8e04-1137209beb7c]  
[2020-12-15 00:00:00,098: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.stats.stats[46f448f1-41d1-4cad-803e-89b3f25bcf11]  
[2020-12-15 00:00:00,102: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.stats.stats[54ef61ef-5f2e-49ea-b7af-84da8e12ee47]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could have happened if you have 3 Celery workers, all started with something like `celery -A <app> worker -B ...` - which basically starts 3 individual schedulers. People often do this mistake... Advice: do not start your Celery workers with beat process embedded (the `-B` option). This option has been added to Celery to make it ease the development. It was never meant to be used in production.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I opened three celery workers processes.

Comment: The problem is not in workers... The problem is that you also started embedded schedulers too.

Comment: I have read the [link](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), know that  do not start your Celery workers with beat process embedded (the -B option),  but  I don't understand why not allow.

Comment: Multiple (N) Celery beat processes running means you will have N duplicated tasks as all N of them will trigger tasks because they are not aware that there are other schedulers out there...